# A question about Vector valued function space

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have been studying functional analysis recently. The professor has already told us about the properties of some special Banach or Hilbert spaces, such as separability, columnarity and representation of dual space.

But if we generalize the function space from the scalar value space to the vector value function space, the conclusion seems to be more complicated.

$C([0,T], X)$ or $L_p[0,T], X)$ When $X$ is Banach or Hilbert space, are they separable and tight? How should the dual space be represented? This makes me very confused.

I hope that someone can provide some guidance on relevant knowledge, and I am grateful for that.